# Extract data using regex Dart/Flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want to extract data from the following

```
Periode Aantal uur Sv-loon
01-06-2019 t/m 30-06-2019 35 € 800,00
01-05-2019 t/m 31-05-2019 35 € 1.056,00
01-04-2019 t/m 30-04-2019 35 € 800,00
01-03-2019 t/m 31-03-2019 35 € 800,00
01-02-2019 t/m 28-02-2019 35 € 800,00
Datum: 06 augustus 2019
```

The expected output is :

```
01-06-2019 t/m 30-06-2019 35 € 800,00
01-05-2019 t/m 31-05-2019 35 € 1.056,00
01-04-2019 t/m 30-04-2019 35 € 800,00
01-03-2019 t/m 31-03-2019 35 € 800,00
01-02-2019 t/m 28-02-2019 35 € 800,00
```

Check what I tried so far  [example](https://regex101.com/r/ZXQTIw/1)

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: I would advise you to check the question guidelines to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its works with the following expression  , ((?<=Sv-loon)([\\S\\s]*?)(?=Datum:))

Comment: You want to remove the first and end line only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Sv-loon\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*Datum:
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VgeXYd/1). **Details**:

- `Sv-loon` - a literal string
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `Datum:` - a literal string

See Dart demo:

```
String txt = "Periode Aantal uur Sv-loon\n01-06-2019 t/m 30-06-2019 35 € 800,00\n01-05-2019 t/m 31-05-2019 35 € 1.056,00\n01-04-2019 t/m 30-04-2019 35 € 800,00\n01-03-2019 t/m 31-03-2019 35 € 800,00\n01-02-2019 t/m 28-02-2019 35 € 800,00\nDatum: 06 augustus 2019";
 RegExp rx = RegExp(r'Sv-loon\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*Datum:');
 Match match = rx.firstMatch(txt);
 if (match != null) {
     print(match.group(1));
 }
```

Output

```
01-06-2019 t/m 30-06-2019 35 € 800,00
01-05-2019 t/m 31-05-2019 35 € 1.056,00
01-04-2019 t/m 30-04-2019 35 € 800,00
01-03-2019 t/m 31-03-2019 35 € 800,00
01-02-2019 t/m 28-02-2019 35 € 800,00
```

Answer (score 0):

**Extract Date only:**

```
void main() {

String inputString = "Your String 1/19/2023 9:29:11 AM";
  RegExp dateRegex = new RegExp(r"(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})");
  Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = dateRegex.allMatches(inputString);
  for (RegExpMatch m in matches) {
    print(m.group(0));
  }
}
```

***This will output:
1/19/2023***

**Extract Date and time:**

```
void main() {

String inputString = "Your String 1/19/2023 9:29:11 AM";
  RegExp dateTimeRegex = new RegExp(r"(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M)");
  Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = dateTimeRegex.allMatches(inputString);
  for (RegExpMatch m in matches) {
    print(m.group(0));
  }
}
```

***This will output: 1/19/2023 9:29:11 AM***

Answer (score -1):

```
RegExp re = new RegExp("((?<=Sv-loon)([\\S\\s]*?)(?=Datum:))");
```

Where `?=` is a Positive Lookahead.